# How to integrate Crisp SDK in react native

Tags: react-native

I try this lib https://github.com/walterholohan/react-native-crisp-chat-sdk#readme but its not working in ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got reply from crisp to use following URL as webview

```
https://go.crisp.chat/chat/embed/?website_id=your_web_id
```

For more info you can check it out here

https://help.crisp.chat/en/article/how-can-i-embed-the-crisp-chatbox-in-an-external-link-bkfh98/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more react native based answer. Install the package react-native-webview and use the following code to embed your crisp chat as a webview.

```
import React from 'react';
import {WebView} from 'react-native-webview';

const WebViewer = ({route}) => {
  return <WebView source={{uri:'https://go.crisp.chat/chat/embed/?website_id=your_website_id'}} />;
};

export default WebViewer;
```